# configurations of the drawer of kendo ui Mobile do not work

Tags: kendo-mobile

This is the skeleton of my KendoUI Mobile app:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
        <!-- Kendo UI Mobile CSS -->
        <link href="styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <!-- jQuery JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Kendo UI Mobile combined JavaScript -->
        <script src="js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>
        <title>Degrado Ambientale</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- View Map -->
        <div data-role="view"  data-title="Degrado Ambientale" id="map-view" data-layout="default" data-stretch="true">
            ...
        </div>

        <!-- View List -->
        <div data-role="view" data-title="Degrado Ambientale" id="list-view" data-layout="default" data-show="app.getDataFromServer" >
            ...
        </div>

        <!-- View New -->
        <div data-role="view" data-title="Degrado Ambientale" id="new-view" data-layout="default" data-show="app.clearRepo">
            ...
        </div>

        <!-- View User -->
        <div data-role="view" data-title="Degrado Ambientale" id="user-view" data-use-native-scrolling="true" class="newformstyle" data-show="app.showOptionView" data-init="app.initOptionView">
            ...
        </div>

        <!--  View Dettagli Segnalazione -->
        <div data-role="view" id="view-repoDetail" style="width: 100%; height: 100%" data-show="app.loadRepo">
            ...
        </div>

        <!-- Default Layout -->
        <div data-role="layout" data-id="default">
            <div data-role="header">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <a data-role="button" data-rel="drawer" href="#drawer" data-icon="drawer-icon" data-align="left"></a>
                    <span data-role="view-title"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Drawer -->
        <div data-role="drawer" data-views='["map-view", "list-view", "new-view"]' data-swipe-to-open="false" id="drawer">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-type="group">
                <li>Men&ugrave
                    <ul>
                        <li data-icon="globe"><a href="#map-view" data-transition="none">Mappa</a></li>
                        <li data-icon="list-icon"><a href="#list-view" data-transition="none">Segnalazioni</a></li>
                        <li data-icon="compose"><a href="#new-view" data-transition="none">Segnala</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>Opzioni
                    <ul>
                        <li data-icon="contacts"><a href="#user-view" data-transition="none">Utente</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and `javascript/index.js` is:

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application($(document).body,{
    init: function(){
        app.navigate('#user-view');
    }
});

    ....

app.initialize = function() {
    this.bindEvents();
};
app.bindEvents = function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
};
app.onDeviceReady = function() {
    ....
};
```

I want to disable drawer-opening via swipe and the drawer must be displayed only on the views with IDs: map-view, list-view and new-view.

To do this, i set the drawer configuration attributes:

- `data-swipe-to-open` to `"false"`;
- `data-views` to `'["map-view", "list-view", "new-view"]'`

but the drawer does not appear in any view. If i delete `data-views` config then the drawer is displayed in all views via swipe.

Answer (score 0):

WRT the data-swipe issue - there is a known issue in Kendo where it does not work on Android (you can still swipe to open the menu - works fine on iOS).

I downloaded the kendoui.complete.2013.3.1324.trial and extracted the kendo.mobile.min.js and css files and it fixed the issue.